# How to properly implement a generic method?

Tags: c#, linq, generics

Can someone help me figure out how to implement this method generically? The compiler complains that it cannot resolve t.Id. Which makes sense but, how do I tell it that all objects that pass will have an Id property. Here is the interface I defined for T:

```
namespace LiveWire.Model
{
    public interface ILiveWireModel
    {
        Guid Id { get; }
    }
}
```

The interface for all repositories:

```
internal interface ILiveWireRepository<T>
{
    ICacheProvider Cache { get; }
    string CacheKey { get; }

    SqlConnection CreateConnection();

    IEnumerable<T> GetData<TD>();

    IEnumerable<T> LoadData<TD>();

    Dictionary<Guid, T> GetCachedData<TD>();

    void ClearCache();
}
```

And my method:

```
public IEnumerable<T> GetData<TD>()
        where TD : ILiveWireModel
    {
        var data = GetCachedData<TD>();

        if (data == null)
        {
            data = LoadData<TD>().ToDictionary(t => t.Id);

            if (data.Any())
            {
                Cache.Set(CacheKey, data, 30);
            }
        }

        return data.Values;
    }
```

I'm including the whole class here which I hope will clear some things up.

```
internal abstract class LiveWireRepositoryBase<T> : ILiveWireRepository<T>
{
    public ICacheProvider Cache { get; private set; }
    public string CacheKey { get; private set; }

    internal LiveWireRepositoryBase()
    {
        Cache = new DefaultCacheProvider();
    }

    public SqlConnection CreateConnection()
    {
        return new SqlConnection(
            ConfigurationManager
            .ConnectionStrings["LiveWire4Database"]
            .ConnectionString);
    }

    public IEnumerable<T> GetData<TD>()
        where TD : ILiveWireModel
    {
        var data = GetCachedData<TD>();

        if (data == null)
        {
            data = LoadData<TD>().ToDictionary(t => t.Id);

            if (data.Any())
            {
                Cache.Set(CacheKey, data, 30);
            }
        }

        return data.Values;
    }

    public IEnumerable<T> LoadData<TD>()
    {
        return new List<T>();
    }

    public Dictionary<Guid, T> GetCachedData<TD>()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }


    public void ClearCache()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

I'm getting this error which I don't understand. I tried using an explicit interface implementation but, that wound up making me remove my where constraint.

> The constraints for type parameter 'TD' of method 'LiveWire.Data.Repositories.LiveWireRepositoryBase.GetData()' must match the constraints for type parameter 'TD' of interface method 'LiveWire.Data.Repositories.ILiveWireRepository.GetData()'. Consider using an explicit interface implementation instead.  C:\projects\LiveWire\Solution\LiveWire.Data\Repositories\LiveWireRepositoryBase.cs  32  31  LiveWire.Data

Comment: You haven't shown the definition of `LoadData`.  Also, `GetData` isn't generic here, you need `GetData<T>()` not `GetData()`.

Comment: Upvoted - Not sure why down voted, seems a legitimate question to me.

Comment: @CAbbott Well, there's a *lot* of information missing.  And since the method here isn't generic it won't compile for entirely different reasons than what the OP is saying, meaning we aren't seeing his real code.

Comment: @Servy - True enough, but a "please add some info" comment fixes that. Just seems there's been a lot of unnecessary down voting going on.

Comment: @CAbbott You mean like [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14760452/how-to-properly-implement-a-generic-method/14760505#comment20659726_14760452)?  I didn't downvote until this rather poor question was upvoted, but I certainly wouldn't criticize anyone for downvoting this question without commenting.

Comment: Without know what Data Actually contains, as per the contents of the GetCachedData and LoadData functions, its hard to finish this off.  I assume what you are really looking for though is T Constraints, letting the code know that the generic T is in fact going to be something that implements a certain interface, and as such will have certain properties available to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exception you get at this stage just says that the interface definition

```
IEnumerable<T> GetData<TD>();
```

hasn't got the same constraints (i.e. the `where`) for the type parameter `TD` as the implementation

```
public IEnumerable<T> GetData<TD>() where TD : ILiveWireModel
```

You need to put the same constraint in the interface.

Answer (score 1):

You'll be able to make this method compile by changing the class's signature to

```
public sealed class MyCache<T> where T : ILiveWireModel
```

(or, if the class is in a different namespace, `where T : LiveWire.Model.ILiveWireModel`).

That said, I'm not sure that this change will solve your problem.  I have only seen a few snippets of your project's code, so I may be wrong, and take the following with a grain of salt:

Is it really the best design to keep GUID-keyed and integer-keyed values in the same cache?  Presumably, you're taking data from two different sources, one which uses GUID keys and one which uses integer keys.  But in the future, what if you add a third source, which also uses integer keys?  The keys from the two integer-key sources could clash, and your cache would always be wrong for some queries.  Personally, I'd maintain a second table or function (maybe keep a table of mappings for integer-valued keys, just pass through the GUID-valued keys) somewhere that knows the mapping from objects to keys, and use that function whenever I need to check if an object is cached.  All the rest of the time, then, your cache could work directly in terms of keys and values, and not have to mess with different types of keys.

Comment: I've tried this a few times and really eyeballed it but, I'm not seeing a positive result. The compiler says constraints are not allowed on non-generic declarations when I do this: public IEnumerable<T> GetData()
            where T : LiveWire.Model.ILiveWireModel

Comment: @SteeleKennett That's because your "generic" method isn't even generic.

Comment: @Servy As you commented, I edited and added everything after the first three lines.  Certainly a shared opinion.

Comment: @SteeleKennett See the edit, which points out a change to the class that will likely allow the class to compile.  That said, think deeply about the design of your system.  I pointed out a few issues in the next two paragraphs.

Comment: @AdamMihalcin There are other problems, such as, as I said, his method isn't generic, nor is LoadData, so even his "hack" is a long way off.  I also agree that his use of `dynamic` is inappropriate, but my point is that not only is this a mean hack, it's not even a *working* mean hack.

Answer (score 0):

```
public IEnumerable<T> GetData<T>() where T:LiveWire.Model.ILiveWireModel { 
  //.../

}
```

Specialization of generics.

Comment: The method isn't generic, so it can't have constraints.

Comment: That's just the start of the problems.  `LoadData` isn't generic either, and also needs to have the constraint, and it could have all sorts of things going on in it's implementation that are relevant to this answer, such as deeper levels of calls that need to be generic.

Comment: @Servy at the moment, we don't have the info for `LoadData()` and the methods it calls. So, can you remove the DV?

Comment: You're right, we don't have the info for that method, which means that the question doesn't provide enough information to be answered and thus shouldn't be answered, and probably should just be closed.  Your answer is wrong, in that it won't work.  Just because you can't fix it with what you know doesn't mean it's "correct".  Since it's wrong, I will most certainly not take off my downvote.

Comment: @Servy, oh well, wouldn't make any difference to me actually :-P hit my 200 cap a few hours ago. So, even the +1 was of no use to me.

Comment: It's not about the rep, it's about indicating to both the OP and to future readers of this question that this is an answer, when it's not.  The rep loss is just a means to encourage you to do what you *should* do with an answer that's wrong, which is to either edit it to make it correct (which you can't do until the OP adds more info) or to delete the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to fix the declaration first

```
public IEnumerable<T> GetData<T>()
```

then, in order to know what you can use ON T, you have to tell it what T is allowed to be.

```
public IEnumerable<T> GetData<T>() where T : ILiveWireModel
```

Finally, you haven't told us what `var data` actually contains, that would be inside of the `GetCachedData` and the `LoadData` Functions, which you dont pass T into and we dont have any idea what it returns.

I would expect to see something like this though

```
public IEnumerable<T> GetData<T>() where T : ILiveWireModel
{
    var data = GetCachedData<T>();

    if (data == null)
    {
        data = LoadData<T>().ToDictionary(t => t.Id);

        if (data.Any())
        {
            Cache.Set(CacheKey, data, 30);
        }
    }

    return data.Values;
}
```